# dbt - how to have create table make an autoincrement column

Tags: identity, dbt

We are building a data warehouse, and leaning towards dbt (data build tool). In the process of writing the model, we need to have an autoincrement (identity) column. How do we instruct dbt to make that part of the `create table` statement that it creates?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. I recently had this as a requirement and I was not able to solve for an auto-incrementing id. But, I also pushed back hard on the necessity of this. The nice thing with modern warehouses is that calculations are fast - you'd probably be better off using the dbt surrogate_key macro to just calculate a hash on the fly (collision probably is vanishingly low). It's deterministic (meaning it'll compute the same every time assuming the underlying data doesn't change) and you don't have to worry about managing state.

Comment: Relevant support discussion for this approach in dbt discourse:
https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/generating-an-auto-incrementing-id-in-dbt/579/2

Answer (score 1):

I will mention the workaround that helped me for this issue.
For Databricks SQL Warehouse:

1. I created the table first on unity catalog with an expected schema and an [identity column](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/08/08/identity-columns-to-generate-surrogate-keys-are-now-available-in-a-lakehouse-near-you.html) on it.
2. Created  custom incremental materialization. Just modified existing incremental.sql file to accept the ignore_column config. You can add any identity or other auto-generated columns into it, so that dbt completely ignores them. From [here](https://github.com/faros-ai/faros-community-edition/blob/main/dbt-transforms/macros/incremental.sql) you can get the script to add that new config. But used databricks adapter incremental.sql macro as a base.
3. Copied [merge.sql](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/ea5a9da71ef71cc13414cd8c2f8097448add5edb/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/models/incremental/merge.sql#L5-L48) file to my macros folder as well. I added it because, for some reason the custom materialization was still doing "insert *" instead of "insert columns".
4. Copied [is_incremental.sql](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/main/core/dbt/include/global_project/macros/materializations/models/incremental/is_incremental.sql#L2) macro and modified it to accept the new custom incremental materialization. Very basic change `model.config.materialized == 'incremental' or model.config.materialized == 'incremental_custom'`

For Snowflake the process is much easier:

1. Create your incremental model as you would normally do
2. Alter table to include your sequences as a primary key. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/norton120/kimball_dbt/blob/master/dimensions/CUSTOMER.sql):